# Issue with RestAPI for threatAssessmentRequests using Microsoftgraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to connect with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequests

getting below error :
401
{

"error": {

```
"code": "Unauthorized",

"message": "Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource.",

"innerError": {

  "date": "2020-11-06T15:21:22",

  "request-id": "8f4d480e-2916-4501-904b-0ca13db9e85e",

  "client-request-id": "8f4d480e-2916-4501-904b-0ca13db9e85e"
```

I am using python3.7 and code looks like :

```
token ="xyz.dslkdskds_123"
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
query1={
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.urlAssessmentRequest","url": "info.cvx.com", "contentType":"url",
  "expectedAssessment": "block", "category": "phishing"
}
url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequests"
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=json.dumps(query1))
```

Comment: can you please provide the required permissions Delegated (work or school account) ThreatAssessment.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Do you still need help on this issue? If yes, please share the information which is mentioned above.

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity : Hi Sruthi, I have given the permission.                  
 "user.read", "mail.send","ThreatAssessment.ReadWrite.All","ThreatAssessment.Read.All"

Comment: I found the remark at MS portal that "Threat assessment permissions are valid only on work or school accounts." Does it mean corporate account does not support this feature ?

Comment: Can you please let us know  what do mean by corporate account

Comment: Sorry - It's a typo. I mean to say does some features have only for some specific account type. I am bit confused with the error . Any suggestion for the error msg - Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource ?

Comment: please let us know are you able to get the data from graph explorer?

Comment: Not exactly-  I'm getting same error : "code": "Unauthorized",

"message": "Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource.",

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue when I run the below query without required permissions in graph explorer

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequests
```

[image]

```
"error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource."
```

But after providing the required permission  `ThreatAssessment.ReadWrite.All` able to get the data

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response . I have given these permissions . When I use Oauth2.0 method for authorization , I get the token and able to do post and get method for informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequests .But I have to enter the credential in the browser manually ,then only I get token. Is there any way to get authentication done and token generated without entering manual credential ?

Comment: In such a situation, you can use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token)